# does MSMQ have "lock until expire" functionality similar to Amazon SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, msmq

I've been using AWS SQS, which has a nice feature that when a message is claimed from the queue it locks for a period of time. During this lock if it is processed successfully the message is marked as completed. If the processing fails (and no response is received from the message processor), after a period of time the lock expires and the message is available for another processor to pick up.

Now I have a requirement to use queues outside of SQS (mostly for latency reasons, but potentially for cost reasons too). I'm really looking for a queue provider that has the same characteristic. MSMQ would be the obvious choice for me, since it's already installed and we use it elsewhere, but I can't find any functionality that handles failed messages in the same way.

Does MSMQ allow for this, or is there an easy way to replicate it?

Alternatively, is there another lightweight, open-source messaging service that does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSMQ does this already. If you read a message within a transaction and the transaction aborts then the message will reappear in the queue.

Comment: thanks, it looks like Transactional messages is what I was looking for